# min-height: 100% ignored in Firefox when set to display: table

Tags: html, css, firefox

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6vEp/1/

`min-height` is completely ignored when the div is set to `display: table`. Seems this is a bug from the latest Firefox update, as this was working fine before I updated my browser. Any other solutions for vertically centering while still maintaining `min-height`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the CSS specification, `min-height` does not apply to table columns.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights

However, the `height` value is actually treated as a minimum height value.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout

In your layout, simply use `height` with a suitable minimum value and your will be okay.  If your table-cell content gets long enough, the height of the table will expand to display the content.